# Boostrap using fixed navbar and anchor tags to jump to sections

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use anchor tags to navigate to specific sections of a webpage using bootstrap and a navbar that is fixed to the top. The problem is when I click the anchor links, they don't correctly scroll to the start of the section, it scrolls past the section start,  because of the margin applied to the body.

```
body {
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```

How can I fix this?

See the following jsFiddle for a full demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6kwrY/

Comment: Are you sure it's because of the margin?

Comment: Well the margin is required, or else the content starts beneath the navbar.

Comment: It's not because of the margin, but because the navbar is overlapping your section

Comment: My point was that it's not the margin, as @OneTrickPony said.

Comment: If you can add `padding-top: 60px;` to each section, that would solve your problem...

Comment: Adding `padding-top: 60px` to all sections destroys the styles though, I don't want sections to have all that padding above them.

Comment: See answers from the linked Q (add negative margin to cancel the padding)

Comment: Thanks that worked for clicking the anchor tags, but BootStrap scrollspy is not selecting current correctly. **Fixed** using `data-offset` on the scollspy body.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solution is to use:

```
.section {
    padding-top: 60px;
    margin-top: -60px;
}
```

Comment: IMO this answer is better than the ones on the "duplicate"...those assume you have `<a name>` tags floating around. With HTML5 and bootstrap `role=navigation` you can have `<section>` tags and this answer works perfectly for those.

Comment: This easy hacky solution works and may be applied even by Bootstrap in-build classes such as `pt-2 mt-n2`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add a margin via padding for all section p's unless they are called 'first'.

```
body {
    margin-top: 60px;
}

section p {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

#first p {
        padding-top: 0px;
}
```