# Bootstrap Navbar (along with topbar) anchor tag navigates content behind the navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I do have the topbar along with navbar with anchor tag in the same page. When I click on the anchor tag the content of anchortag does go behind the navbar. Please find below the code: HTML:

```
<body>
        <!-- Full Body Container -->
        <div id="container">
        <!-- Start Header Section -->
        <header id="header-wrap" class="site-header clearfix">
             <!-- Start Top Bar -->
            <div class="top-bar">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-7 col-sm-8 col-xs-6">
                    <!-- Start Contact Info -->
                    <ul class="contact-details hidden-xs">
                      <li>
                        <a href="contact.html">
                        <i class="icon-envelope">
                        </i>
                         <span class="hidden-xs">the email address</span>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">
                        <i class="icon-call-out">
                        </i>
                        <span class="hidden-xs"> Call Us: 123456789 </span>
                        </a>
                      </li>                 
                    </ul>
                    <!-- End Contact Info -->
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-5 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <!-- Start Social Links -->
                    <ul class="social-list">
                      <li class = "hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
                        <a href="#">
                        <i class="icon-call-out">
                        </i>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class = "hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
                        <a href="#">
                        <i class="icon-envelope">
                        </i>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#" class="social-link facebook" title="Facebook" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#" class="social-link twitter" title="Twitter" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#" class="social-link google" title="Google Plus" href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#" class="social-link linkdin" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Linkedin" href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- End Social Links -->
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Top Bar -->
            <!-- Start  Logo & Navigation  -->
            <div id= "fixedbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-top" role="navigation" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="50">
              <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <!-- Stat Toggle Nav Link For Mobiles -->
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                  <!-- End Toggle Nav Link For Mobiles -->
                  <div class="logo-wrapper">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                      <img src="assets/img/logo6.png" alt="SB Construction">
                    </a>  
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!--  Brand and toggle menu for mobile ends  -->
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                  <!-- Start Navigation List -->
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                      <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li id= "toplinks">
                              <a href="#whoweare">
                              Who We Are
                              </a>
                            </li>
                            <li id= "toplnks">
                              <a href="#ourvision">
                              Our Mission
                              </a>
                            </li>
                            <li id= "toplnked">
                              <a href= "#ourvision">
                              Our Vision
                              </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="services.html">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <!-- End Navigation List -->
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Mobile Menu Start -->
              <ul class="wpb-mobile-menu">
                    <li>
                      <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li id= "mbil1">
                              <a href="#whoweare">
                              Who We Are
                              </a>
                            </li>
                            <li id= "mbil2">
                              <a href="#ourvision">
                              Our Vision
                              </a>
                            </li>
                            <li id= "mbil3">
                              <a href= "#ourmission">
                              Our Mission
                              </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="services.html">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>
              </ul>
              <!-- Mobile Menu End -->
            </div>
            <!-- End Header Logo & Navigation -->
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </header>
          <!-- End Header Section -->
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.top-bar {
      background: #EEEEEE;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    .top-bar .contact-details li {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 8px 0;
    }
    .top-bar .contact-details li a {
      font-size: 14px;
      display: block;
      margin-right: 15px;
      color: #999;
      line-height: 32px;
    }
    .top-bar .contact-details li a i {
      padding-right: 5px;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .top-bar ul.social-list {
      float: right;
      padding: 8px 0;
    }
    .navbar-top.affix {
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 9999999;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
      animation-duration: 1s;
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
      animation-fill-mode: both;
      -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
      animation-name: fadeInDown;
    }
    .navbar-top.affix .logo-wrapper {
      margin-top: 15px;
      margin-bottom: 18px;
    }
    .navbar-top.affix .logo-wrapper .navbar-brand img {
      width: 100px;
    }
    .navbar-top.affix .navbar-nav > li {
      padding: 15px 0!important;
    }
    .navbar-top.affix .search-side {
      top: 15px;
    }
    .navbar-top.affix .full-search {
      top: 67px;
    }
    .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      background: #fff;
      border: none;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
      border-radius: 0;
      -webkit-border-radius: 0;
      -moz-border-radius: 0;
      -o-border-radius: 0;
    }
    .logo-wrapper {
      margin-top: 19px;
      margin-bottom: 17px;
      float: left;
    }
    .navbar-brand {
      padding-bottom: 0px;
      display: block;
      height: auto;
      padding-top: 0;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav {
      margin-right: 5px!important;
      position: relative;
      transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
      padding: 31px 0;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
      color: #999;
      display: block;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
      padding: 7px 16px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: 700;
      border-radius: 0px;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:hover > a,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a.active {
      color: #ffbb02;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a i {
      margin: 0 -2px 0 -5px;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 100%;
      width: 260px;
      background-color: #fff;
      visibility: hidden;
      z-index: 999;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.drop:hover .dropdown {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .dropdown li,
    .sup-dropdown li {
      position: relative;
      border-bottom: 1px dotted #eee;
    }
    .dropdown li:last-child,
    .sup-dropdown li:last-child {
      border-bottom: none;
    }
    .dropdown li a,
    .sup-dropdown li a {
      display: block;
      color: #666;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 400;
      padding: 11px 16px;
      margin: 0;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: capitalize;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    .dropdown li a i {
      margin: 0 0 0 -4px;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .sup-dropdown {
      position: absolute;
      left: 100%;
      top: 0;
      width: 260px;
      background-color: #fff;
      margin-top: 10px;
      transition: margin-top 0.2s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: margin-top 0.2s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition: margin-top 0.2s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: margin-top 0.2s ease-in-out;
      visibility: hidden;
      z-index: 3;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav li.drop .dropdown li:hover .sup-dropdown {
      visibility: visible;
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    .dropdown > li:hover > a,
    .sup-dropdown li:hover > a {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #ffbb02;
    }
    .dropdown li a.active,
    .sup-dropdown li a.active {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #ffbb02;
    }
    .nav > li.drop:hover ul.dropdown {
      display: block;
      -webkit-animation: drop-up 400ms ease both;
      -moz-animation: drop-up 400ms ease both;
      -o-animation: drop-up 400ms ease both;
      animation: drop-up 400ms ease both;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .js #wpb-mobile-menu {
        display: none;
      }
      .js .slicknav_menu {
        display: block;
      }
    }
```

Here is my Javascript I searched through stackoverflow posts:

```
$("#toplinks, #toplnks, #toplnked").on('click','a', function(event){ 
event.preventDefault();
var o =  $( $(this).attr("href") ).offset();   
var sT = o.top - $("#fixedbar").outerHeight(true); 
window.scrollTo(0,sT);
});
```

So whenever I click on the anchor tag the content of ID "whoweare" will start from top of the page (behind the navbar). Please note I do have topbar on the top of navbar, which(topbar) on scroll gets hidden and navbar placed at top.

Also note, I have added the code for the index page (first page), the same code of topbar and navbar I will use for other pages (e.g: services, projects etc). 
Please help me out to make my navbar functions properly.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem with the provided code. Some code is missing. Have a look at this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/zZqELm) and please, fork it and complete it... **OR** provide a live URL.

Comment: This is a common issue when using a fixed navbar (or any fixed content at the top). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181355/boostrap-using-fixed-navbar-and-anchor-tags-to-jump-to-sections

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Thank you for the codepen but I am not able to reproduce the same as I am using bootstrap theme and it does need several theme predefined css and js. However I pasted all but codepen does not allow I think. I will try to show you the live website work by other method..

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette hi, I have created the code in w3school and adding below the link to identify the issue. Here the mobile version does not work properly but Laptop size screen does work properly. the link:https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FDBAQCN4F7W7

Comment: I've made you a complete detailled answer. Have a look! ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Thank you so much.. I appreciate your time figuring out the problem and the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working...
Please, read these detailled explanations.

**first**: 
Using jQuery, you have to use selectors that actually exist in your HTML.
In your script, `"#toplinks`, `#toplnks`, `#toplnked` and `#fixedbar` just refer to absolutely nothing.

The impact was that your script simply never triggered at all.
The scroll effect you were observing was the natural default behaviour of a link click.

**Second**: 
You have two "special cases" where this script should not do the same thing as for the other links.

1. "Section 1" needs to scroll to window position zero in order to show the `top-nav`.
   It should not calculate an offset.
2. "Section 4" opens a sub-menu showing "Section 4-1" and "Section 4-2".
   Since this "Section 4" also is a link, you have to remove its useless `href` attribute (`href="#"`).
   Then in the script, you have to check if `$(this).attr("href")` is defined to avoid script error.

I left many explicative `console.log()` because I'm pretty sure that you will play with this menu to add elements to it.

You will certainly notice that the script runs twice on the sub-menu items.
That is because the event is "bublling" to its parent (the "Section 4" `a`).
But this is no big deal.

If you try to stop this "bubbling" effect, you'll break the Bootstrap action on the menu.
So just remove or comment out all `console.log()` on your final page.
;)

**Here is the script**
And here is a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/gmMxxj?editors=1011), which you can play with (and see how I made it working).

```
console.clear()
console.log("READY!");

$(".navbar-nav li").on('click','a', function(event){ 
  event.preventDefault();

  // Which link was clicked?
  console.log($(this).attr("href"));

  // Section 1 case:
  if( $(this).attr("href")=="#section1" ){
    $("body").scrollTop(0);
    console.log("Window simply has to scroll to position: 0");
  }

  // Section 4 case (Or any link which triggers a sub-menu)
  if(typeof($(this).attr("href"))=="undefined"){
    console.log("This link shall NOT trigger a scroll.");
  }

  // All the other cases.
  if(typeof($(this).attr("href"))!="undefined" && $(this).attr("href")!="#section1"){

    var o =  $( $(this).attr("href") ).offset();   
    var sT = o.top - $(".navbar").outerHeight(true);
    window.scrollTo(0,sT);

    console.log("Section offset is: "+o.top);
    console.log("Nav bar height is: "+$(".navbar").outerHeight(true));
    console.log("Window has to scroll to position: "+sT);

  }

  // Just an empty console line for clarity.
  console.log("");
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. I spent almost entire day to figure it out and you helped me to get out of this mess..I thank you from the bottom of my heart and I appreciate your time figuring out the problem and solution..

Comment: Hi, Louys. Sorry, I am again showing up! You resolved my question regarding the navbar. I was working on my website preparation and needed to look into this question again. I am not able to understand the `var o =  $( $(this).attr("href") ).offset();`  Would you please let me know what does this var o means and how the value is calculated? [I believe it refers to the body sections having id as "section 1" and so on, but I am not able to interpret from jQuery code - I read as "select element having attribute of href" ]. Thank you..

Comment: Hi! Let's decompose this line in 4 parts. **1-** `var o` is a variable declaration, which I called `o`. I could have called it `sectionPosition`. It is just a variable name. **2-** `$(this).attr("href")` returns the `href` of the clicked anchor in the nav bar. So when it is wrapped by `$()`, it is interpreted as a selector and targets the element having this `id`, which is the targetted `section`.

Comment: **3-** We now have the element to scroll to... We need its position. [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) is used to find it. It returns an object containing the `top` and `left` position. That is what the `o` variable now contains. **4-** So to get the `top` position needed in the calculation, `o.top` return the `top` position of the targetted section. This is the distance, in pixel, from the very top of the page. We need the page to scroll to that position ***minus*** the height of the navbar. `st` contains the result of the calculation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time Louys. I understood  parts 1,3 and 4 perfectly. Just to confirm my understanding of 2nd (e.g if I have clicked for section 1 in navbar): `$(this).attr("href")` returns `#section1`. Now we have wrapped that in `$()` hence it will be like `$(#section1)` and it will return the offset of paragraph having ID "section1"... Awesome.. Which book do you refer for all this JQuery ? I want to learn about the scroll events like position() and offset().. You are the best !! God Bless you..

Comment: `$(#section1)` returns an element. You can now use it to get information about it or manipulate it. The part that returns the offset is `.offset()`. The "book" I use is the [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/)... Or Google search on a jQuery method I want to have more details... ;)